# How to make connection between map icon and my svg image

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am making a custom plugin where i have to give client functionality to add new marker & drag & drop marker to any location in my map(svg image). On marker click popup will show that particular location details. How should i make connection between location and marker div or any other alternate.

Comment: You could use AJAX to load in the details based on that plot, if you add and parse the plot if in a `data-plot` attribute.

Comment: @JamieBicknell thanks, but how willl i be able to show particular information on marker click as marker will be changing it's information. something like this- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/821/